# Segmentation fault in Python script using Aerospike Tornado

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tornado, aerospike

Any idea why i am getting segmentation fault, the python script runs fine for about an hour or so and suddenly causes a segmentation fault.
The script uses tornado ioloop for making periodic call to update data to Aerospike database and a separate periodic function for making few http request. Below is backtrace from gdb

```
    #0  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000052d17b in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0x7ffff43309b0, for file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py, line 1027, in _schedule_next (self=<PeriodicCallback(_running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _next_timeout=<float at remote 0xdc8250>, callback=<functools.partial at remote 0x7ffff42e3730>, callback_time=10000, _timeout=<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326170>, io_loop=<EPollIOLoop(_impl=<select.epoll at remote 0x7ffff7f6f4c8>, _handlers={4: (<_socketobject at remote 0x7ffff4823c20>, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b398>), 6: (6, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b2a8>)}, _running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _callbacks=[], _thread_ident=140737353992000, _callback_lock=<thread.lock at remote 0x7ffff4a8a3d0>, _cancellations=130, _events={}, time_func=<built-in function time>, _timeout_counter=<itertools.count at remote 0x7ffff4329cf8>, _waker=<Waker(writer=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aae0>, reader=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aa50>) at remote 0x7ffff4824c90>, _stopped=False, _closing=False, _timeouts=[<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326200>, ...(truncated), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2375
#2  0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7ffff5d68cb0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=<optimized out>, argcount=argcount@entry=1, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3252
#3  0x000000000052ca8d in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=1, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffd3b0, func=<function at remote 0x7ffff5adab90>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4116
#4  call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffd3b0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4041
#5  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0xdd7d70, for file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py, line 1024, in _run (self=<PeriodicCallback(_running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _next_timeout=<float at remote 0xdc8250>, callback=<functools.partial at remote 0x7ffff42e3730>, callback_time=10000, _timeout=<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326170>, io_loop=<EPollIOLoop(_impl=<select.epoll at remote 0x7ffff7f6f4c8>, _handlers={4: (<_socketobject at remote 0x7ffff4823c20>, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b398>), 6: (6, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b2a8>)}, _running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _callbacks=[], _thread_ident=140737353992000, _callback_lock=<thread.lock at remote 0x7ffff4a8a3d0>, _cancellations=130, _events={}, time_func=<built-in function time>, _timeout_counter=<itertools.count at remote 0x7ffff4329cf8>, _waker=<Waker(writer=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aae0>, reader=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aa50>) at remote 0x7ffff4824c90>, _stopped=False, _closing=False, _timeouts=[<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326200>, <_Timeout at rem...(truncated), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
#6  0x000000000056d0aa in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (closure=<optimized out>, defcount=<optimized out>, defs=0x0, kwcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, argcount=14515568, args=<optimized out>, locals=0x0, globals=<optimized out>, 
    co=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:3252
#7  function_call (func=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>, kw=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/funcobject.c:526
#8  0x000000000052e1e6 in PyObject_Call (kw={}, 
    arg=(<PeriodicCallback(_running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _next_timeout=<float at remote 0xdc8250>, callback=<functools.partial at remote 0x7ffff42e3730>, callback_time=10000, _timeout=<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326170>, io_loop=<EPollIOLoop(_impl=<select.epoll at remote 0x7ffff7f6f4c8>, _handlers={4: (<_socketobject at remote 0x7ffff4823c20>, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b398>), 6: (6, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b2a8>)}, _running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _callbacks=[], _thread_ident=140737353992000, _callback_lock=<thread.lock at remote 0x7ffff4a8a3d0>, _cancellations=130, _events={}, time_func=<built-in function time>, _timeout_counter=<itertools.count at remote 0x7ffff4329cf8>, _waker=<Waker(writer=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aae0>, reader=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aa50>) at remote 0x7ffff4824c90>, _stopped=False, _closing=False, _timeouts=[<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326200>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff42e5170>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326518>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7fffeba97248>, <_Timeout at...(truncated), func=<function at remote 0x7ffff5adab18>) at ../Objects/abstract.c:2529
#9  ext_do_call (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffd5b0, func=<function at remote 0x7ffff5adab18>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4333
#10 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=f@entry=Frame 0x7ffff42ed430, for file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py, line 275, in null_wrapper (args=(), kwargs={}, current_state=((...), None)), 
    throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2705
#11 0x000000000056d0aa in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (closure=<optimized out>, defcount=<optimized out>, defs=0x0, kwcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, argcount=-198257616, args=<optimized out>, locals=0x0, 
    globals=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:3252
#12 function_call (func=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>, kw=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/funcobject.c:526
#13 0x00000000004a70c3 in PyObject_Call (kw=<optimized out>, arg=(), func=<function at remote 0x7ffff5d79e60>) at ../Objects/abstract.c:2529
#14 partial_call (pto=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, kw=0x0) at ../Modules/_functoolsmodule.c:205
#15 0x000000000052cc20 in PyObject_Call (kw=0x0, arg=(), func=<functools.partial at remote 0x7ffff42e32b8>) at ../Objects/abstract.c:2529
#16 do_call (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffd7f0, func=<functools.partial at remote 0x7ffff42e32b8>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4238
#17 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffd7f0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4043
#18 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0xdbb520, for file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py, line 592, in _run_callback (self=<EPollIOLoop(_impl=<select.epoll at remote 0x7ffff7f6f4c8>, _handlers={4: (<_socketobject at remote 0x7ffff4823c20>, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b398>), 6: (6, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b2a8>)}, _running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _callbacks=[], _thread_ident=140737353992000, _callback_lock=<thread.lock at remote 0x7ffff4a8a3d0>, _cancellations=130, _events={}, time_func=<built-in function time>, _timeout_counter=<itertools.count at remote 0x7ffff4329cf8>, _waker=<Waker(writer=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aae0>, reader=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aa50>) at remote 0x7ffff4824c90>, _stopped=False, _closing=False, _timeouts=[<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326200>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff42e5170>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326518>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7fffeba97248>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff42f1518>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff43211b8>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326b90>, <_Timeout at re...(truncated), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
#19 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7ffff5dd7c30, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=<optimized out>, argcount=argcount@entry=2, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3252
#20 0x000000000052ca8d in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=2, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffd9d0, func=<function at remote 0x7ffff5ad9f50>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4116
#21 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffd9d0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4041
#22 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0xe23bb0, for file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py, line 813, in start (self=<EPollIOLoop(_impl=<select.epoll at remote 0x7ffff7f6f4c8>, _handlers={4: (<_socketobject at remote 0x7ffff4823c20>, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b398>), 6: (6, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b2a8>)}, _running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _callbacks=[], _thread_ident=140737353992000, _callback_lock=<thread.lock at remote 0x7ffff4a8a3d0>, _cancellations=130, _events={}, time_func=<built-in function time>, _timeout_counter=<itertools.count at remote 0x7ffff4329cf8>, _waker=<Waker(writer=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aae0>, reader=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aa50>) at remote 0x7ffff4824c90>, _stopped=False, _closing=False, _timeouts=[<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326200>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff42e5170>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326518>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7fffeba97248>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff42f1518>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff43211b8>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326b90>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7...(truncated), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
#23 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7ffff5d682b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=<optimized out>, argcount=argcount@entry=1, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3252
#24 0x000000000052ca8d in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=1, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffdbb0, func=<function at remote 0x7ffff5ada488>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4116
#25 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffdbb0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4041
#26 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0x7ffff4330b90, for file /home/tbehra/may/super/build/python/tools/krait_2_x/nf/as_dtr/tornado_ioloop.py, line 24, in start_ioloop (stop_timer=None, ioloop=<EPollIOLoop(_impl=<select.epoll at remote 0x7ffff7f6f4c8>, _handlers={4: (<_socketobject at remote 0x7ffff4823c20>, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b398>), 6: (6, <function at remote 0x7ffff431b2a8>)}, _running=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _callbacks=[], _thread_ident=140737353992000, _callback_lock=<thread.lock at remote 0x7ffff4a8a3d0>, _cancellations=130, _events={}, time_func=<built-in function time>, _timeout_counter=<itertools.count at remote 0x7ffff4329cf8>, _waker=<Waker(writer=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aae0>, reader=<file at remote 0x7ffff4a5aa50>) at remote 0x7ffff4824c90>, _stopped=False, _closing=False, _timeouts=[<_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326200>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff42e5170>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff4326518>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7fffeba97248>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff42f1518>, <_Timeout at remote 0x7ffff43211b8>, <_Time...(truncated), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
#27 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7ffff48069b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=<optimized out>, argcount=argcount@entry=0, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x7ffff4808628, defcount=1, 
    closure=0x0) at ../Python/ceval.c:3252
#28 0x000000000052ca8d in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=0, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffdd90, func=<function at remote 0x7ffff480d0c8>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4116
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#29 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffdd90) at ../Python/ceval.c:4041
#30 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0x7ffff4320420, for file /home/tbehra/may/super/build/python/tools/krait_2_x/nf/as_dtr/as_dtr_emulation.py, line 338, in start_application_server_instance (instance_id=7, call_model_object=<KraitCallModel(stats_hp_refresh_timer=10, response_delay_time=3, sgd_call_model=None, db_port=3000, s6c_call_model=None, instance_no=7, rest_call_model=<type at remote 0xcc1480>, db_ip=['10.0.0.125', '10.0.0.125'], interface=3, run_duration=500, stats_lp_refresh_timer=30) at remote 0x7ffff482f450>, appserver=<ApplicationServerAuto(_auto_mode=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, appserver_ip='127.0.0.1', vendor=<VerizonSMS(receiver_msisdn_min=9075000000, receiver_per_message=1, url_get='/rest/sms/delivery-status/', receiver_msisdn_max=9079999999, receiver_msisdn=9075007230, sender_msisdn=9071007230, sender_msisdn_min=9071000000, sms_content='VERIZON SMS', correlator=1000000001, sender_msisdn_max=9074999999, url_post='/rest/sms/messages', interfacename='REST') at remote 0x7ffff430dcf8>, notify_percent=0, max_retry=10, url_not...(truncated), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
#31 0x000000000052cf32 in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, n=2, pp_stack=0x7fffffffded0, func=<function at remote 0x7ffff480dd70>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4106
#32 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffded0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4041
#33 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0xcdb8f0, for file nf_emulation.py, line 169, in main (opt=<Values(node_identity='AS_DTR', ip=None, port=None, mtcgw_ip=None, instance=7, mode='EMULATION', mtcgw_port=None, file_path='../configs/call_model.cfg', relay_host=None) at remote 0x7ffff430def0>, args=[], file_path='../configs/call_model.cfg', node_identity='AS_DTR', port=None, instance_no=7, host=None, relay_host=None, emulation_flag=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, log_file_name='AS_DTR7', call_model_obj=<KraitCallModel(stats_hp_refresh_timer=10, response_delay_time=3, sgd_call_model=None, db_port=3000, s6c_call_model=None, instance_no=7, rest_call_model=<type at remote 0xcc1480>, db_ip=['10.0.0.125', '10.0.0.125'], interface=3, run_duration=500, stats_lp_refresh_timer=30) at remote 0x7ffff482f450>, select_thread_id=None, l_log_level=20), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
#34 0x000000000052cf32 in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, n=0, pp_stack=0x7fffffffe010, func=<function at remote 0x7ffff431b140>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4106
#35 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffe010) at ../Python/ceval.c:4041
#36 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=f@entry=Frame 0x7ffff7f8c440, for file nf_emulation.py, line 184, in <module> (), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
#37 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7ffff7ec2530, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3252
#38 0x00000000005b7392 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=co@entry=0x7ffff7ec2530, 
    globals=globals@entry={'parser': <OptionParser(process_default_values=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, allow_interspersed_args=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _long_opt={'--mtcgw_ip': <Option(_long_opts=['--mtcgw_ip'], help='IP Address of mtcgw', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mtcgw_ip', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4307200>, '--port': <Option(_long_opts=['--port'], help='Listening Port for Node', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='port', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='int', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4832758>, '--mode': <Option(_long_opts=['--m', '--mode'], help='[TERMINAL] and [EMULATION] mode', callback_args=None, callback=None, default='EMULATION', nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mode', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', meta...(truncated), 
    locals=locals@entry={'parser': <OptionParser(process_default_values=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, allow_interspersed_args=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _long_opt={'--mtcgw_ip': <Option(_long_opts=['--mtcgw_ip'], help='IP Address of mtcgw', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mtcgw_ip', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4307200>, '--port': <Option(_long_opts=['--port'], help='Listening Port for Node', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='port', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='int', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4832758>, '--mode': <Option(_long_opts=['--m', '--mode'], help='[TERMINAL] and [EMULATION] mode', callback_args=None, callback=None, default='EMULATION', nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mode', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', meta...(truncated)) at ../Python/ceval.c:667
#39 0x0000000000469663 in run_mod.42576 (mod=<optimized out>, filename=<optimized out>, 
    globals={'parser': <OptionParser(process_default_values=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, allow_interspersed_args=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _long_opt={'--mtcgw_ip': <Option(_long_opts=['--mtcgw_ip'], help='IP Address of mtcgw', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mtcgw_ip', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4307200>, '--port': <Option(_long_opts=['--port'], help='Listening Port for Node', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='port', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='int', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4832758>, '--mode': <Option(_long_opts=['--m', '--mode'], help='[TERMINAL] and [EMULATION] mode', callback_args=None, callback=None, default='EMULATION', nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mode', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', meta...(truncated), 
    locals={'parser': <OptionParser(process_default_values=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, allow_interspersed_args=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _long_opt={'--mtcgw_ip': <Option(_long_opts=['--mtcgw_ip'], help='IP Address of mtcgw', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mtcgw_ip', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4307200>, '--port': <Option(_long_opts=['--port'], help='Listening Port for Node', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='port', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='int', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4832758>, '--mode': <Option(_long_opts=['--m', '--mode'], help='[TERMINAL] and [EMULATION] mode', callback_args=None, callback=None, default='EMULATION', nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mode', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', meta...(truncated), flags=<optimized out>, arena=<optimized out>) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1370
#40 0x00000000004699e3 in PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=fp@entry=0x984260, filename=filename@entry=0x7fffffffe69e "nf_emulation.py", start=start@entry=257, 
    globals=globals@entry={'parser': <OptionParser(process_default_values=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, allow_interspersed_args=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _long_opt={'--mtcgw_ip': <Option(_long_opts=['--mtcgw_ip'], help='IP Address of mtcgw', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mtcgw_ip', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4307200>, '--port': <Option(_long_opts=['--port'], help='Listening Port for Node', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='port', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='int', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4832758>, '--mode': <Option(_long_opts=['--m', '--mode'], help='[TERMINAL] and [EMULATION] mode', callback_args=None, callback=None, default='EMULATION', nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mode', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', meta...(truncated), 
    locals=locals@entry={'parser': <OptionParser(process_default_values=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, allow_interspersed_args=<unknown at remote 0x91fe10>, _long_opt={'--mtcgw_ip': <Option(_long_opts=['--mtcgw_ip'], help='IP Address of mtcgw', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mtcgw_ip', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4307200>, '--port': <Option(_long_opts=['--port'], help='Listening Port for Node', callback_args=None, callback=None, default=None, nargs=1, choices=None, dest='port', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='int', metavar=None) at remote 0x7ffff4832758>, '--mode': <Option(_long_opts=['--m', '--mode'], help='[TERMINAL] and [EMULATION] mode', callback_args=None, callback=None, default='EMULATION', nargs=1, choices=None, dest='mode', container=<...>, _short_opts=[], action='store', const=None, callback_kwargs=None, type='string', meta...(truncated), closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffffffe250) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1356
#41 0x0000000000469f1c in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=fp@entry=0x984260, filename=<optimized out>, filename@entry=0x7fffffffe69e "nf_emulation.py", closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffffffe250)
    at ../Python/pythonrun.c:948
#42 0x000000000046a018 in PyRun_AnyFileExFlags (fp=fp@entry=0x984260, filename=filename@entry=0x7fffffffe69e "nf_emulation.py", closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffffffe250) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:752
#43 0x000000000046ab81 in Py_Main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x7fffffffe408) at ../Modules/main.c:640
#44 0x00007ffff7818ec5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x46ac3f <main>, argc=8, argv=0x7fffffffe408, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe3f8) at libc-start.c:287
#45 0x000000000057497e in _start ()
```

Comment: Don't know if it helps: the only time I had python SIGSEGV on me was when I was using the same database connection (read: external module compiled in C) in parallel threads.

Comment: Nothing in that stack trace mentions aerospike at all, so it's impossible to tell how the two are failing to interact.  The Python client for Aerospike is synchronous, so that may have something to do with it, in general.

Comment: Finally figured it out its an issue with aerospike api is_connected(), have raised a issue with aerospike community

Comment: Is this still a problem with the Python client 2.0.3?